# Why does my Coregraphics drawingcode cause lag?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm working on an drawing app for iPhone. It works fine for like 5 seconds in the iPhone simulator but as more I draw it gets more laggy. When I test it on the device it gets even more laggy and I can't even draw a simple tree. When I check how high percent the processor is running at in xcode it usually go between 97-100%. Is there any way to fix this?

```
(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {     
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 568));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),path);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
}
```

Comment: You should externalize your context (define it at a higher level, perhaps as an ivar of your class) and re-use it on every touch. You wouldn't need recreating it over and over again.

Comment: Also, avoid calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` so frequently. Just call it once and assign the result: `CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

Comment: Also, here you're re-adding `drawImage` on each frame. That might be a big performance hit.

Comment: could you tell me more in detail. Im pretty new to objective C.

Comment: "Also you are re-adding draw image for each frame" Yeah thats what i thought too.

Comment: Try using instruments on that issue. You can simply open that method and see the percentage of performance, that every single line takes in that method. From there, you can start "mature" optimization :D

Comment: As you can see from instruments, re-adding drawImage is not the problem. Although, he will definitely end up with a really huge view hierarchy that way... getCurrentContext is also no heavy operation. Just getting a reference.

Answer (score 1):

When running instruments on your method, I got the following results:

[image]

What that tells me:

- Setting up a new context every time you want to draw something is
  waste of time. consider only setting it up once, store it somewhere, 
  and you save almost a third of the time, the method currently needs
- drawImage is the other most-consuming part. It will be enough to set that only once!
- all other calls are almost negligible

Comment: +1 for your answer. Could you show me how to fix it?

Comment: As cyrille said, make a property for your context and reuse it (just as you do with your drawImage image view). And I´m not entirely sure why you need to call the "drawImage" method at all. That should happen automatically when you set the drawImage´s image. Also rethink whether you really have to add the drawImage to your viewHierarchy every time. Setting the image on it is enough for your UI to display the image!

Answer (score 1):

There's a great talk about graphics performance including a demo and code walkthrough of a drawing app here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

The **iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations** video

Comment: Thanks, though my codes is pretty different to the demo example.

Comment: Perhaps you can take some inspiration from the methods used by the Apple performance engineers.