# How to clear the lines drawn on uiview that are drawn using touch point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, cgcontext, uitouch

I am working on requirement where i need to draw the lines on UIImageView along with the touch points. I need to clear all the drawings from UIImageView on button click. I was able to draw the lines but not able to clear lines on button click. I even want to implement clear all and undo options too.Can someone please guide me in the way where i can implement clear all and undo options. Below is the code that i am using to implement drawing. Not sure how to implement clear all and undo drawing.

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:_selectedImageView];

 _ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(_ctx);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.selectedImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.selectedImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[self.selectedImageView setAlpha:opacity];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

Comment: Well, realize that what you're doing is creating a new image with every call to UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). So to clear them all you can simply create a blank/empty image (just size and fill a graphic context). Note that using your above approach for multiple touch points is very inefficient (creating a graphics context is expensive). Take a look at this answer for a better understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177856/touchesmoved-drawing-in-cashapelayer-slow-laggy/22261323#22261323

Comment: Thanks MDB983. your information is helpful. But i was able to find a solution from here <https://github.com/backslash112/paint-with-undo/tree/master>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the solution for my question to clear the points or lines drawn from the below sample. I was able to implement both clear all and undo by following the below sample from github.
https://github.com/backslash112/paint-with-undo/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

```
private func clear(from: CGPoint?, to: CGPoint?, lineWidth: CGFloat = 34) {
    guard let from = from, let to = to, let image = imageView?.image, let size = imageView?.bounds else { return }
                   
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setLineCap(.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context?.setBlendMode(.clear)
    
    image.draw(in: size)
    
    context?.move(to: from)
    context?.addLine(to: to)
    context?.strokePath()
    
    let newCGImage = context?.makeImage()
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    if let newCGImage = newCGImage {
        let img = UIImage(cgImage: newCGImage)
        imageView?.image = img
    }
}
```